# How to Apply Encrypt/Decrypt in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, email, encryption

Im using in PS the next command:

```
"Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

This generate a Key that im saving as "Key.txt" file

Now i want to decrypt that password using this:

```
$password = Get-Content password.txt (or just copy-pasting the key)
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,($password | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```

BUT...

how i supose to add that to this...

```
$EmailFrom = "MyMail@gmail.com"
$EmailTo = "MayMail@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "Test" 
$Body = "this is a Test" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("My_USer", "My_Password"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

I want to add it as My_Password, of course i should add a variable $password that comes from the Key.txt file for example, but then...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we save the credentials

```
"Password123" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\key.txt -NoNewline
```

Then we can use it just like this :

```
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("SomeServer", 587)
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist ThisIsAUserName ,($(Get-Content C:\key.txt) | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```

And we can check to make sure it loaded correctly like this :

```
$SMTPClient.Credentials | select username, password
```

The output looks like this

```
UserName        Password   
--------        --------   
ThisIsAUserName Password123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ArcSet its working. Now i think is not the best way to protect a credential... but its a good start.

Comment: @Citrusl I think it depends on how you will use those credentials. Is it for you user only? or will you share it among users? Currently ConvertTo-SecureString uses DPAPI and if you are using it to keep this password just for your use then this is just fine. If you are wanting to have other users access this and use it and they arnt supposed to see the password ...then this solution is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, storing in plain text is not good at all, but if you are not concerned about that then it's there.

You have other options, with secure / encrypted files and Windows CredMan:

[Quickly and securely storing your credentials – PowerShell](https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell)

To get a credential object we can either manually create one or use the Get-Credential cmdlet to prompt for the account details:

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
```

To store the credentials into a .cred file:

```
$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path "${env:\userprofile}\Jaap.Cred"
```

And to load the credentials from the file and back into a variable:

```
$Credential = Import-CliXml -Path "${env:\userprofile}\Jaap.Cred"
Invoke-Command -Computername 'Server01' -Credential $Credential {whoami}
```

[Securely Store Credentials on Disk](http://powershellcookbook.com/recipe/PukO/securely-store-credentials-on-disk)

[Allow multiple users to access credentials stored using export-clixml](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/allow-multiple-users-to-access-credentials-stored-using-export-clixml)

[How to run a PowerShell script against multiple Active Directory domains with different credentials](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/11/30/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-against-multiple-active-directory-domains-with-different-credentials)

PowerShell Credentials Manager
CredMan.ps1 is a PowerShell script that provides access to the Win32 Credential Manager API used for management of stored credentials.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde

And modules to use

https://powershellgallery.com/packages/BetterCredentials
https://powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager
https://powershellgallery.com/packages/IntelliTect.CredentialManager

Comment: Wow thanks @postanote, i will play with those commands for a while.

Comment: No worries. Options are always a good thing, and grants breathing room for an educated decision.